# How can I set the CSS class of an element in a Rails view?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

How can I set the class of an element in a Rails view's haml?

For example, suppose I want to set the CSS class of a `%td%` element that's written like this to the "red" class:

```
%td= book.author
```

How would this be written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like [Haml](http://haml.info/docs.html).

You can use either `%td.red= book.author` or `%td{:class => "red"}= book.author`.

Comment: Yes, I'm a total RoR newbie taking a class; I assumed `haml` is a given?

Comment: Not necessarily! Rails can use many templating languages, include ERB (the default), Haml, Slim, and a number of others. Haml is definitely popular though. :)